# Gatling fetching from csv file

Tags: gatling

I have created a Gatling simulation, by creating a ".har" file from Google Chrome. And I have changed input parameters & trying to fetch data from a ".csv" file.
Now when I run the simulation, how can I check if Gatling simulation has fetched data fields from ".csv" file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporarily lower logging level to DEBUG in conf/logback.xml, you'll see the requests that are being generated.

Answer (score 1):

Gatling has quite good **error handling/logging** connected to feeders.

1. When you provide wrong file name or path of your feeder file you will get following error (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate feeder file). Note that tests will not run.

   ```
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
   at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate feeder file: file gatling/src/test/resources/data/wrongFile.csv doesn't exist
   at io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederSupport$class.feederBuilder(FeederSupport.scala:53)
   at io.gatling.core.Predef$.feederBuilder(Predef.scala:22)
   at io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederSupport$class.separatedValues(FeederSupport.scala:44)
   at io.gatling.core.Predef$.separatedValues(Predef.scala:22)
   at io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederSupport$class.separatedValues(FeederSupport.scala:41)
   at io.gatling.core.Predef$.separatedValues(Predef.scala:22)
   at io.gatling.core.feeder.FeederSupport$class.csv(FeederSupport.scala:34)
   at io.gatling.core.Predef$.csv(Predef.scala:22)
   at com.scenario.Scenario.<init>(Scenario.scala:10)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
   at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.io$gatling$app$Gatling$$$anonfun$1(Gatling.scala:41)
   at io.gatling.app.Gatling.run(Gatling.scala:92)
   at io.gatling.app.Gatling.runIfNecessary(Gatling.scala:75)
   at io.gatling.app.Gatling.start(Gatling.scala:65)
   at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.start(Gatling.scala:57)
   at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.fromArgs(Gatling.scala:49)
   at io.gatling.app.Gatling$.main(Gatling.scala:43)
   at io.gatling.app.Gatling.main(Gatling.scala)
   ```
2. When your attribute will not matched column name from feeder you will get following error. All tests will end with error.

   ```
   00:10:07.937 [ERROR] i.g.h.a.s.HttpRequestAction - 'httpRequest-1' failed to execute: No attribute named 'wrongAttributeName' is defined
   ```
3. When you have empty file with feeder data you will get following error.

   ```
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
      at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.runMain(MainWithArgsInFile.java:50)
      at io.gatling.mojo.MainWithArgsInFile.main(MainWithArgsInFile.java:33)
   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Feeder is now empty, stopping engine
      at io.gatling.core.action.SingletonFeed$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(SingletonFeed.scala:61)
      at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:482)
      at io.gatling.core.akka.BaseActor.aroundReceive(BaseActor.scala:23)
      at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
      at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
      at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
      at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
      at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
      at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
   ```

When non of this appear you can be almost sure that everything is ok. But to **verify parameters send by Gatling** you can check

1. Gatling logs (change logging level to DEBUG) in logback.xml

   ```
   <root level="DEBUG">
       <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
   </root>
   ```

   And then you will see log similar to

   ```
   00:13:53.233 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.s.HttpTx$ - Sending request=Action name uri=http://your-rest-service?param1=value1&param2=value2: scenario=com.scenario.Scenario Scenario name, userId=1
   ```
2. Access logs on your server. In Tomcat instruction you can get for example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39008)